# Iterate through objects in objects in Firebase using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I did some reading on my problem & while a lot of people pointed to using `DataSnapshot.forEach()` to solve my issue, I would like to know if it's possible to modify my query inside `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` to fit my needs.

[image]

This is the structure I currently have where a `Request` may have 1 or many `Orders`. Each `Order` comes with its set of values such as `restaurantID`. 
I want to basically iterate through all those requests & only display the ones that have an order with a certain `restaurantID`.

In my application, the user logs in & has a value for `restaurantID`. I want to show inside my RecyclerView only the orders that are related to that account, based on that value.

Below is the code. I tried to do some funny stuff in `populateViewHolder()` to fix this with `ordersForThisRestaurant` but it did not quite work out. I would love any help on this, I have been stuck & wasn't able to make any progress for some time. Would be awesome to advance!

THANK YOU!

***OrderStatus.java***

```
public class OrderStatus extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Request, OrderViewHolder> adapter;

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference requests;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_status);

        //Initialize the Firebase database.
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        requests = database.getReference("Requests");

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerOrder);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        loadOrders();
    }


    private void loadOrders() {
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Request, OrderViewHolder>(
                Request.class,
                R.layout.order_layout,
                OrderViewHolder.class,
                requests
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(OrderViewHolder orderViewHolder, Request request, int i) {
                List<Order> activeOrders = request.getOrder();
                List<Order> ordersForThisRestaurant = new ArrayList<>();
                for(int pos=0; pos<activeOrders.size(); pos++) {
                    Order currentOrder = activeOrders.get(pos);
                    String restaurantID = currentOrder.getRestaurantID();
                    if(restaurantID.equals(Common.currentUser.getRestaurantID())) {
                        ordersForThisRestaurant.add(activeOrders.get(pos));
                    }
                }
                if(ordersForThisRestaurant.size() == 0) return;     //This means the request was not for this restaurant.

                orderViewHolder.orderID.setText(adapter.getRef(i).getKey());
                orderViewHolder.orderStatus.setText(Common.convertCodeToStatus(request.getStatus()));
                String orderMenu = "";

                for(int pos=0; pos<ordersForThisRestaurant.size(); pos++) {
                    String currentMenu = ordersForThisRestaurant.get(pos).getMenuName();
                    String currentQuantity = ordersForThisRestaurant.get(pos).getQuantity();
                    //orderMenu += currentMenu + " x" + currentQuantity + " | ";
                    if(pos != 0) {
                        orderMenu += "\n";
                    }
                    orderMenu += currentQuantity + " " + currentMenu;
                }

                orderViewHolder.orderMenu.setText(orderMenu);
                orderViewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                        //Empty -> just to fix crash because of context menu
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

***OrderViewHolder.java***

```
public class OrderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnCreateContextMenuListener{

    public TextView orderID;
    public TextView orderStatus;
    public TextView orderMenu;

    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public OrderViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        orderID = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderID);
        orderStatus = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderStatus);
        orderMenu = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderMenu);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Select an action");
        menu.add(0, 0, getAdapterPosition(), "Update");
        menu.add(0, 1, getAdapterPosition(), "Delete");

    }

    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //No onClick => otherwise it throws an error.
        //itemClickListener.onClick(v, getAdapterPosition(), false);
    }

}
```

***Request.java***

```
public class Request {
    private String email;
    private String name;
    private List<Order> order;
    private String restriction;
    private String status;

    public Request() { }

    public Request(String email, String name, String restriction, List<Order> order) {
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;
        this.restriction = restriction;
        this.order = order;
        this.status = "0";          //0: Placed. 1: Ready. 2: Picked up.
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public String getRestriction() {
        return restriction;
    }
    public void setRestriction(String restriction) {
        this.restriction = restriction;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public List<Order> getOrder() {
        return order;
    }
    public void setOrder(List<Order> order) {
        this.order = order;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your order contains single order all the times or may add another?

Comment: They may contain multiple orders. You can have a sandwich & a pizza in the same order for instance.

Comment: Sorry, I think I understood what you asked. Each ```Request``` will have one ```Order``` list. In this list, you can have multiple objects that correspond to a specific food option that was in the user's cart. If the user orders a pizza & a sandwich, ```Order``` will have an object with ID = 0 & ID = 1 corresponding to those two elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve the data according to the `resturantID`, then you need to do the following:

```
 requests = database.getReference("Requests").child("1582094998206").child("order");
 Query resturantQuery = requests.orderByChild("restaurantID").equalTo("01");
```

Then use `resturantQuery` inside the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Comment: Wouldn't this only work for that one request with ID ```1582094998206```? I want to iterate through all the requests stored in the database.

Comment: didnt u want this `I want to basically iterate through all those requests & only display the ones that have an order with a certain restaurantID`?

Comment: Sorry, I must've said it wrong. I want to go through request ```1582094998206```, ```1582095037988``` & any other request in the database. Then, for each, I would check the ```order``` array. Within this array, I want to display the objects that have ```restaurantID == "01"``` for instance. Does it make sense?

Comment: You can create a query `orderByKey().startAt(152..)` then add a listener to it, this will retrieve the data then inside the onDataChange u iterate and do another query but this time it will be like this `child(key).child("order").orderByChild("resturantID").equalTo("01")` and then use that query in the recyclerview

Comment: I am not 100% sure what this means but it gives me pointers & I'll try it out later today. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found a solution. Continuing that route with the current database schema I had didn't seem like a viable option so I worked on restructuring what that looked like. Using the regular `.orderByChild(restaurantID).equalTo("01")` worked from there.

Something I was about to explore if this did not work out was building my own `Adapter` & `ViewHolder` and find some way of retrieving the needed data with Firebase's `ValueListener`.